# process in python for loop slows down, even when resetting the list

Tags: python, for-loop, memory-management

Hi this might be a silly question...

but my process in `for` loop slows down with it reaches around the 40,000 th loop

 For example

```
lst = []
for i in range(100000):

    result = do something with my code
    lst.append(result)

    if len(lst) == 5000:
         "save list as pickle then reset"
         lst = []
```

Is this because python saves up memory stash(?) during the for loop? so the size of list won't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to call `gc.collect()` after `lst = []` so that the garbage collector frees up the memory from the last 5000 items.

Garbage collectors (generally) are hard to predict so it's likely that the script is not releasing the memory after the reference is reassigned.

Comment: Also just for fun - this seems like a good candidate for parallel execution.  If each chunk of 5000 items doesn't depend on the last 5000 items, then change your python script to accept a "start" and "end" parameter, then start a bunch of them at once in a bash script.